# jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget Plugin not passing data from HTML Form to PHP mailer

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use images in Jquery UI Multiselect Widget. Everything seems to work great except when I try to pass the list of select colors to php to be emailed. In the email I only received the last selected item, so if I select black and blue, I only receive blue in the email.

I'm using this html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery MultiSelect Plugin Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="multiselect/style.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="multiselect/jquery-ui.css" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="multiselect/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="multiselect/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

  // custom text
   $("#colors").multiselect({
    header: false,
    height: 250,
    noneSelectedText: 'Select Color Group(s)',

       });

    });
   </script>

   <body>

   <h1>Form Submission Test</h1>
   <p>Testing to ensure the correct values are actually passed when the form is submitted.</p>

   <form action="colors_mail_handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-top:20px">
   <select id="colors" name="colors" multiple="multiple" size="8">
   <option value="beige"       image="menu_stuff/material_beige.png">   &nbsp Beige</option>
   <option value="black"       image="menu_stuff/material_black.png">   &nbsp Black</option>
   <option value="blue"        image="menu_stuff/material_blue.png">    &nbsp Blue</option>
   <option value="brown"       image="menu_stuff/material_brown.png">   &nbsp Brown</option>
   <option value="burgundy"    image="menu_stuff/material_burgundy.png">&nbsp Burgundy</option>

   </select>

   <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
   </form>

   <!--
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").bind("submit", function(){
        alert( $('#colors').serialize() );
 return false;
   });
   </script> 
    -->

   </body>
   </html>
```

and using this PHP to send the email:

```
  <?php 
       $to = "memail@gmail.com"; 

       $subject = "Colors submission";

       $message =  $_POST['colors'];


       mail($to,$subject,$message);

       ?>
```

I have run the commented out code in the HTML that gives me an Alert with the 'colors' variable and it is correct.

Anyone have any ideas or things I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Your need to put brackets in the `<select>` name:

```
<select id="colors" name="colors[]" multiple="multiple" size="8">
```

This way the selected values are sent and retrieved by php in an array in `$_POST['colors']`.
You can then implode the array to get a string to send by email:

```
$message = 'No color selected';
if (isset($_POST['colors'])) {
    $message = implode(', ', $_POST['colors']);
}
```